# Adding new object properties in ng-repeat for each object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm fairly new with AngularJS so please excuse my ignorance and improper terminology.

I have a Controller called activitiesController that returns an array of activity objects.  Each activity object has some properties which I can display in the view using ng-repeat="activity in activities".

One of the properties is a big string that I need to hack apart and essentially add to new properties of the activity object (I know this is horrible but it's from a legacy system).

Do I run a function in ng-repeat like ng-repeat="activity in getNewProperties(activities)" where I would loop through each activity and return the array back to ng-repeat.

OR

Do I just make a function in the scope that will return each property that I'm looking for.

Ideally in the view I would just use activity.newDetails.NewValue which makes me beielve i need to run my function on all of the activity objects before they are passed to ng-repeat in the view.

Sorry I know this isn't very details I can try to add more shortly.

Comment: It is best to make the data that the view binds to 100% what it needs to be.  In other words, don't try to ng-repeat over something that is not quite what you want.  Transform it first, then bind it.  Probably not best to use a function in this case, since the transform could run many many times.

Comment: Thanks for your response that does make alot of sense.  Something just hadn't quite clicked yet.  I appreciate your explanation. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I run a function in ng-repeat like ng-repeat="activity in getNewProperties(activities)" where I would loop through each activity and return the array back to ng-repeat.

Let's say you did this and the function looks something like this:

```
$scope.getNewProperties = function(activities) {
  var modifiedActivities = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < activities.length; i++) {
    var modifiedActivity = activities[i];
    modifiedActivity.foo = "bar";
    modifiedActivities.push(modifiedActivity);
  }
  return modifiedActivities;
};
```

This function will run in every $digest cycle. Besides from being resource consuming, it also means that if you make changes to modified properties (in this case `foo`), the next time this function runs, the property will be overwritten by this function.

What you want to do is modify `$scope.activities` as soon as you get the data. This way it will only occur once unless you refresh the data. e.g.

```
$http.get("http://somewebsite/api").then(function(response) {
  $scope.activities = response.data;

  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.activities.length; i++) {
    // modify properties
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  That helps me understand the best way to achieve what I was looking for.